# bootstrap 4 toggle is not working during convert bootstrap theme to angular 9 project?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, toggle, angular-bootstrap-toggle

i am converting bootstrap them to  angular 9 project i have properly set all js and css in the angular.json file but toggle not working.check my below attached angular.json and index.html file?

```js
"styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
       "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"  
      "src/assets/css/normalize.css",
      "src/assets/css/main.css",
      "src/assets/css/fullcalendar.min.css",
      "src/assets/css/animate.min.css"       
     ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
       "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js",   
      "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
      "src/assets/js/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js",
      "src/assets/js/Chart.min.js",
      "src/assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"
    ]
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SchoolManagment</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="/assets/image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.png">
    <!-- Normalize CSS -->
    <!-- Main CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/flaticon.css">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and also bootstrap css not working if is set linking in angular.json file and but its not works if i add in index.html file.can anybody tell me what's the wrong i am here?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 => `npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save`

Step-2 => Add bellow files in `angular.json`  `styles` and `scripts` array.

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

Once these steps followed compile your project once again.

Note - Remove css and js link from index.html.

Comment: sir why set above path -- "src/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",? i am using node modules

Comment: sir i follow above steps toggle is working but collpase not working now and  my UI is not showing correct if set bootstrap in angular.json  file UI is break but if i set in index.hml its correct.